# Entity Framework Core: Script-Migration not recognizing migrations when creating script

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I've got a full .NET Framework 4.6.2 Web API app that I've installed Entity Framework Core 1.1.2 into. It contains some classes, a DbContext class and has the relevant EF Core NuGet packages installed.

When I run `Add-Migration Initial` in the package manager console within Visual Studio, it correctly identifies the DbContext in the project and produces the migration class as well as a snapshot. The migration looks correct, given that within the Up method, it shows a number of create tables for each of the classes I want, it shows the expected columns for each and the constraints I'd expect, so that looks good. Also, within the Down method, it drops all the tables (which makes sense since this is the first migration done). This migration class is created in the /Migrations directory within the project.

When I run `Script-Migration` in the console next, it produces a SQL script that is incorrect, in that it only creates the table for the EFMigrationsHistory, as follows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [__EFMigrationsHistory] (
        [MigrationId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
        [ProductVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK___EFMigrationsHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
    );
END;

GO
```

This SQL file is created in the bin/Debug directory for the project.

I would expect that the output of this `Script-Migrations` command contain the SQL version of the Up method in the migration class that was produced by the previous `Add-Migrations Initial` command, but alas, this is not the case. If I run `Update-Database`, it runs against this SQL file and continues to ignore the existing Migrations.

Similarly, this appears to be a larger issue with EF Core, because if I attempt to do a `Remove-Migration` as suggested in the console after running `Add-Migration`, it is also unable to find the Migration it just produced and gives me the following error:

> No ModelSnapshot was found.

And I know this can't be the case because I see it right there in the Migrations folder along with the initial migration class it created.

What's going on and is there any known workaround to get these tools working appropriately?

**Update**

While testing, I've found that if I create a new solution with just these few parts in it, it works fine. However, in my original solution, I have these projects within a number of solution folders, so perhaps that's the issue at hand, because putting the new project in a solution folder causes the same issues observed in the rest of this question.

Comment: Have you tried adding `-Context` or `-Project` [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt614250.aspx)?

Comment: I added the context, project and startupproject parameters, but I still get exactly the same SQL script as in the question, despite the migration class itself looking as expected. I also have tried using the From and To parameters (with 0 and Initial, respectively). It indicated that "The migration 'Initial' was not found", so I tried putting the whole filename and it didn't care for that either.

Comment: To that end, I tried placing the entire path to the migration class in the To parameter and it couldn't find it either. I think the issue is more that it's simply looking in the wrong place for the migrations - is there some way to specify that directory?

Comment: Does adding `-Verbose` give any additional clues?

Comment: Nope, all the paths look right that get passed to the EF function. After experimenting with it all day, I've found that if this project is located at the root of the solution or within a single solution folder, it'll work fine. If I put it into one more nested solution folder, it breaks and I get the same result as the above. My standing workaround is to just move the project to the root, restart VS, do the migration, move it back and restart VS once more.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this.  I am having a similar issue now but my SQL script is empty.